# Ajax add command to open a new URL

Tags: ajax

in a custom module, I created a custom form. On this form, I have an ajax button to open a specific file (.pdf).

Here is my code in a custom submit function :

```
  $url = 'myfileUrl';
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $command = new RedirectCommand($url);
  $response->addCommand($command);
```

It's ok and the file is opened when I click on the button. But, the page is closed to open the file. How can I specify an attribute "target" to open the file in a new window? If not possible, is there another ajax command to open an external URL?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: @kevin, I don't see a clear response in your link. Can you explain me if I can use a target attribute in a RedirectCommand ajax? e.g. $command = newRedirectCommand($url, 'target=_blank', or newOpenUrl...). Thanks.

Comment: According to [RedirectCommand Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21RedirectCommand.php/class/RedirectCommand/8.2.x) RedirectCommand set `window.location` , and it's not possible to redirect with target _blank with window.location, only with window.open(url,'_blank'); can redirect to new window, see the answer in the link commented by @kevin in the first comment.

Comment: @berramou, I understand the behavior of the RedirectCommand function. But, what should I use to open a new window (and open a file) if I click on a button? I tried to use the OpenDialogCommand without sucess. Or, should I use a custom submit and forget the ajax functions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to resolve my problem.
After having readed several posts, i have decided to create a custom Ajax Command to open my files (pdf/csv).

[Create a custom command - link](https://weknowinc.com/blog/creating-custom-ajax-command-drupal-8)

In my custom module, I have built the required files for this and call in my CallBack function this new ajax command ('OpenFileCommand') :

```
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $command = new OpenFileCommand($file_url);
    $ajax_response->addCommand($command);
```

Here is the simple code for this command:

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CommandInterface;

/**
 * Class OpenFileCommand.
 */
class OpenFileCommand implements CommandInterface {

  // Create a new property.    
  protected $file_url;

  // Construct the File Url property.
  public function __construct($file_url) {
    $this->file_url = $file_url;
  }

  /**
  * Render custom ajax command.
  *
  * @return ajax command function
  */
  public function render() {
    return [
      'command' => 'OpenFileCommand',
      'file_url' => $this->file_url
    ];
  }

}
```

Now, I can open a file when I click on a ajax button.

Thanks for all for your help. This solution can help someone...

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new window which can be achieved using javascript. Call function like below using on click method. You have to pass the URL to open and title for the window.

```
    function openWindow(url, title){
      var left = (screen.width/2)-(700/2);
      var top = (screen.height/2)-(500/2);
      var win = window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=700, height=500, top='+top+', left='+left);
      //setTimeout(function () { win.close(); }, 10000); <- You can give timeout also so window will get automatically closed
    }
```

Hope this will help to open your pdf file in new window, I will post another answer if I found to open a new tab on redirect.